# Получить значение метода onResponse в переменную

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, okhttp

Получить значение метода onResponse в переменную.

```
var GLOBAL_VAR:Int? = null
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        doInBackground()
    }
    private var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null
    private var reader: BufferedReader? = null
    private var resultJson = ""
    private var url = URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=53.7095281,91.4277445&DC&destinations=53.696365,91.386070&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyCJYCg5StSenKMjLgEn3zAbAAwpuBESKQc")

    private fun doInBackground() {
        // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
        try {
            urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConnection!!.requestMethod = "GET"
            urlConnection!!.connect()
            val inputStream = urlConnection!!.inputStream
            val buffer = StringBuffer()
            reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            var line: String?
            do {
                line = reader!!.readLine()
                if (line == null)
                    break
                buffer.append(line)
            } while (true)
            resultJson = buffer.toString()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                    .build()
            val request = Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build()
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response?){
                    val responseString = response!!.body()!!.string()
                    val resultJson = JSONObject(responseString)
                    val rows = resultJson.getJSONArray("rows")
                    val obj = rows.getJSONObject(0)
                    val elements = obj.getJSONArray("elements")
                    val element = elements.getJSONObject(0)
                    val distance = element.getJSONObject("distance")
                    var value = distance.getInt("value")
                    value /= 1000
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, value.toString())

                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "some error")
                }
            })
    }
    companion object {
        var LOG_TAG = ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>LOG>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Какое значение? Какую переменную? Задайте вопрос так что бы не только Вам было понятно.

Comment: Да, закрутился. Значение value в любую переменную в методе MainActivity(нужно создать, Int).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Android нельзя синхронно выполнять запросы к сети, да и зачем? Иначе юзеру пришлось бы смотреть на зависнувшее UI и ждать выполнения каждого вашего запроса. Последуйте следующей логике: вы хотите сделать запрос к сети и сохранить потом что-то в переменную, - в этом состоит ваш вопрос, верно?

Тогда почему бы не построить эту логику по-другому: просто сразу вызывайте нужную вам логику, при получении нужного ответа. Допустим, вы хотите сделать запрос к API какого-то сайта и просто напрямую поместить ответ от сервера в какой-нибудь `TextView` - тогда просто делайте запрос к этому API, получайте нужный ответ и передавайте его в метод, который будет содержать вашу логику (например, как я сказал - устанавливать ответ в виде текста на экране).

В котлине есть, например, корутины, или же можно обычным AsynkTask добиться того, чего вы хотите (поместить синхронно данные в переменную) - но зачем?

Comment: Я должен получить значение расстояние от пункта до пункта по ссылке c JSON, после получить переменную value и дальше её катать по активити и другим классам. Предложили вариант с AsyncTask и с делегатом.

Comment: @userBuzzer попробуйте посмотреть на задачу с другой стороны - как я описал в ответе. Я надеюсь, что всю эту логику вы не собираетесь размещать в методе `onCreate` у активити? Тогда создайте, например, отдельный класс, который при инициализации своего экземпляра (например, в конструкторе) получает нужный ответ от сервера и дальше делает с ним, что хочет - вы можете в конструкторе записать этот ответ в какую-нибудь переменную. В итоге будет как раз то, что вам нужно - у вас будет переменная value и вы можете катать её как хотите, и при этом никакой синхронной записи в переменную нет.

Comment: Нет конечно, не onCreate :DDD Буду разбираться, спасибо.